# Determining rpart.control parameters

Tags: r, cart-analysis

Are there any dataset-based rules or or standards for deciding rpart.control parameters when conducting CART analysis in R? For instance, what's the right minsplit and minbucket to use, and what aspects of my dataset does that depend on? How do I determine this?

Comment: This is more about statistical modeling than programming. If you need advice for tuning a statistical model, you should ask over at [stats.se].

Comment: @MrFlick it's an R question - have you used rpart in R before?

Comment: Sure. I've answered questions about it here on on this site. But exactly what you set those parameters to has more to do with your data and what exactly you are trying to model. And knowing what those values should be requires a deep understanding of the statistical model, not just where to pass the parameter in a function.

Comment: @MrFlick my question has been purchased on hold as off-topic by cross-validated site moderators. I was told it is better suited for stack exchange. Quite frankly it is an R question, a programming question that requires a little theoretical explanation in support: what do I set minsplit and minbucket to in rpart function controls in R to get the optimal tree for the nearly 6000 row-10 dependent variables-3 independent variables that I have. I would appreciate an answer if you CART-R code have experience, even a "here's what I used and this is what my dataset was like" answer would be superb!